# Why do some domain names contain numbers and strange words?

Tags: networking, ip

Here are some examples which appear under the foreign address field when I run `netstat` (on Win7):

```
lhr08s06-in-e11
edge-star-shw-12-erc3
```

Why don't these look like standard internet domain names (eg. google.com)? Is there a significance of the dashes (`-`), numbers and words?

Comment: If they don't resolve to Internet host names, they're probably not on the Internet, no? ;)

Comment: Those look like routers. I had an ISP that used to name routers after beer ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** Why don't these look like standard internet domain names?

**A:** Because you're not connecting to domains or domain names, you're connecting to hosts in those domains. Netstat displays your connections to other hosts. When you open your web browser to `www.google.com` you're not connecting to a host named `www.google.com`, you're connecting to a host that serves the web site for `www.google.com` (such as **lhr08s06-in-e11**). When  you see a name in Netstat you're seeing the hostname of the host that you're connected to.

---

From Microsoft:

**Foreign Address**

*The IP address and port number **of the remote computer** to which the socket is connected. **The name that corresponds to the IP address and the port are shown unless the -n parameter is specified**. If the port is not yet established, the port number is shown as an asterisk (*).*

---

So again, you're not connecting to a host named `www.google.com` so that isn't what's going to show ip in Netstat.

In addition, I would be very surprised if you see connections to routers in your Nestat output, unless you're actually connected to a router (using telnet, SSH, etc.). While it's true that your traffic transits many routers, your computer doesn't actually make a connection with those routers.

Comment: Thanks. Since StackOverflow appeared as `stackoverflow.com`, I kind of assumed other sites like google would appear similarly. Not sure why some look human-readable and others don't.

Comment: I have similar reports in Linux, but I have found that the server names have been truncated, and the full names do have a `.com` or equivalent at the end, so they _are_ standard internet names.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see *any* “standard Internet domain names” (fully qualified domain names,
like `anything.com`) in the output of `netstat`? 
What about `netstat -f`? 
Windows’ `netstat` doesn’t display FQDNs unless you specify `-f`.

> Is there a significance of the dashes (`-`), numbers and words?

I don’t know. 
Is there a significance to “kotozna”, “grawity”, “slhck”, “ultrasawblade”, etc? 
They’re names. 
People have a certain amount of discretion (i.e., freedom) in choosing names.

Comment: I see `stackexchange.com`. The `-f` options doesn't help explain. Not sure what you are trying to say about names. Yes my name means something. Does "lhr" mean something is my question? For example, do all routers start with lhr? Or is lhr an acronym? The numbers might also signify something. I find it hard to believe google chose them without some reasoning.

Comment: I’m saying that people are free to name themselves and the things they create however they want, without needing any reason. Google might have some obscure reason for naming their hosts the way they do, or they might just be using a random string generator, and there’s no way we can know unless they tell us. … P.S. I agree with joeqwerty: unless you’ve connected ***to*** your router (in order to login to it and/or reconfigure it), you probably aren’t seeing any routers in `netstat`’s list of Active Connections.